# Pechkin and in-used process in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pechkin, tuespechkin

I use Pechkin for generating pdf in my web application, but i have a problem, when application use it to generate PDF, append to IIS application a in use process and i can not restart application, i have to recycle application pool at first and then restart it.
it's not good for me and i need some solution to dispose this process after use.
use Pichkin in async mode, and call it in this way.

```
PechkinSync.Convert(new GlobalConfig()
    .SetMargins(new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0))
    .SetCopyCollation(true)
    .SetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4)
    .SetOutputFormat(GlobalConfig.OutputFormat.Pdf), htmlcontent);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the Pechkin code. I'd recommend you switch to [Tuespechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin). This is an active fork of Pechkin which includes many bugfixes. Unfortunately active development on Pechkin ceased over [two years ago](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin/commits/master).

Comment: Thank you - had exactly this problem and with Tuespechkin it worked !